# Laradock - Localhost not working on Windows 7 using Nginx

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have setup a laradock app on my local machine. I have followed the instructions as provided: http://laradock.io/

In addition to that as I am on Windows 7, and using Docker toolbox

when access to localhost I get this error This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

With docker toolbox, you won't have some of the networking functionality to hide the embedded VM. Therefore you need to connect to that VM's IP address directly instead of localhost. Use `docker-machine ls` to list the VM and get the IP address for it.